# Hibernate + JPA : How to add extra columns to a one to many join table?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, join

I am designing a Library Management system. 
Entities : User and Book
Join Table : User_Book (one to many relationship between user and the book)
I want to persist the date(extra column) when the user has checked out the book.
How can I do this programmatically?

Comment: where are those "extra columns" represented in your Java model classes? If they aren't in your classes then how can JPA magically invent them?

Answer (score 0):

you should treat the concept of "a user U has checked out book B on date D" as an object of its own, e.g., `class Checkout`.  You can make that an entity on the `user_book` table, and map it as `@OneToMany` from `User`.

Alternatively you could treat the book checkouts as an `@ElementCollection` from the User, which mean that the Checkouts don't get their own ID and can only exist as a child of the user.